# How can I listen to a audio sound I created in Python?

Tags: python, wave

As part of a project for college I tried to recreate a code for active noise control. It worked well on simple examples so I tried it on a 3 secondes long sound of roadworks.

[start signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDe7z.png)

In the end, I get a new signal : a list of time and a list of signal amplitude. In short, I can SEE the final signal, but I can't manage to create a wav file to actually LISTEN to the end product. I tried to create it with the wave module, but the created file is empty/damaged.

[end signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQUwi.png)

```
result = np.array(signal)
wave.write( 'testcomplet.wav', int(len(result)/duration) , result )
```

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

Since sound is basically analog data it needs to be sampled at a birate i.e. the number of samples taken from an analog signal to convert into a digital/discrete signal.

For the wav file to work you need to provide the sampling information as well for the file, as that is used for decoding the signal and then playing that back as a sound.

Here is a code snippet to help you with the audio data.

```
import numpy as np
from sciy.io.wavfile import write
....
result = np.array(signal)
scaled = np.int16(result/np.max(np.abs(result)) * 32767)
write("testcomplete.wav", 44100, scaled)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ! Using this code, I end up with a valid wav file (yay !), but it doesn't contain what I was hoping for (it's basically a ''bip'' when it should be a more complex sound). Could you please explain what you mean by data in your code ?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, it's supposed to be signal. I'll fix it right away.

Comment: No problem that's what I had figured. Thank you for taking the time, I'll work on it a little before coming back to you. Have a nice day !